# How can I grant temporary access to my AWS Organizational Unit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, scp

I am trying to temporarily grant access (break glass scenario) to a parent Organizational Unit, to assume a role called "Engineer" in the child Organizational Unit's (OU) AWS "Development" Account.

How can I effectively accomplish this?

For clarity, let's illustrate the AWS Organization structure as follows:

```
- Root (Management Account)
|-Foo (Parent - OU)
|-- Bar (Child - OU)
```

The current scenario makes this challenging:

- Bar, has an SCP applied that blocks / denies access from ALL OUs. The policy is called "DenyAccessToBar" (Please see below)
- There's an IAM policy in the Bar OU's Development account that allows the Foo OU to perform the sts:AssumeRole action on the "Engineer" role. Please see the policy below

So coming back to my question, how can I effectively implement a break-glass process for the Foo OU? Will the SCP applied on the Bar OU block the Foo OU from assuming the Engineer role in the Bar Ou's AWS Development Account?

**Policies**

1. DenyAccessToBar (applied on the Bar OU).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAllAccessToBar",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEqualsIfExists": {
          "aws:RequesterOrganizationalUnitId": "ou-def1234567890" 
        },
        "StringNotEqualsIfExists": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-123456" 
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2. IAM policy applied in Development Account in Bar OU

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::DEV_ACCOUNT_ID:role/engineer",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-123456"
        },
        "StringEqualsIfExists": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgUnitId": "ou-abc1234567890"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```